# How type alias are implictly converted in go?

Tags: go

I read that in Go, type alias need explicit conversion but the below code works fine. How?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Coartl [][]rune

func (ptr *Coartl) PushFront(str []rune) {
    *ptr = append([][]rune{str}, (*ptr)...)
}

func (ptr *Coartl) PushBack(str []rune) {
    *ptr = append((*ptr), str)
}

func (s Coartl) String() string {
    var ret string

    for _, v := range s {
        ret += string(v)
        ret += string("\n")
    }
    
    return ret
}

func main() {
    var coartl Coartl
    var art [][]rune = [][]rune{
        []rune("Hai"),
        []rune("Hello"),
    }
    
    coartl = art // How this converted
    
    coartl.PushBack([]rune("qwerty"))

    fmt.Print(coartl)
}
```

Output:

```
Hai
Hello
qwerty

Program exited.
```

Edit :

But why bellow code does not work ?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    type Int int
    var i int = 1
    var j Int = i // i is not convertable to j ?
    fmt.Print(i, j)
}
```

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/0EkIodzPcmF)

Comment: Your code does not  contain a single type alias. `type Coartl [][]rune` is the declaration of a named type Coartl with underlying type [][]rune which is **not** an alias. Assignablity (and type aliases) is explained in the langauge spec https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability  just look it up there.

Comment: "I understand that underlying type are reference type when we assign that assign reference to the variable not copy of that? that is correct ?" No this is totally wrong. There are **no** references in Go. Some types have kinda reference semantic (slices, maps, buffered channels), but no type ever is a reference. Forget  about "reference" now and forever, this is a totally misleading concept in Go. It does no god.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a [type alias](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_declarations), it's a type definition. A type alias is of the form `type Coartl = [][]rune` (note the `=`).

You are declaring the type `Coartl` as having underlying type `[][]rune`.

When performing the assignment `coartl = art`, go checks for  [assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability). The spec states (relevant part shown, see the linked spec for the rest):

> A value x is assignable to a variable of type T ("x is assignable to
> T") if one of the following conditions applies:
>
> - ...
> - x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.
> - ...

Since the underlying type of `Coartl` is also `[][]rune`, the assignment can proceed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, can you see updated question, does underlaying type share reference ?

Comment: The underlying type just specifies that type `Coartl` is really made of. This has no impact on what happens to the data itself on assignment. See the spec on [types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Types) for more details. For assignments, Go is always **by value**. In the case of a slice, the slice descriptor is copied, but the underlying array is not. See [slice internals](https://blog.golang.org/slices-intro) for important details about slices.

Comment: @Srilakshmikanthan, because none of the conditions in the spec apply. The one that does apply to the slice types does not apply to int and Int because both types are defined types.